# Python 1 of 2 stop conditions gets ignored in a loop

Tags: python, numpy, loops, math

I am writing this simple function to use power iteration for the dominant eigenvalue. I want to put 2 stop conditionals. One for iterations and one for a precision threshold. But this error calculation does not work.
What a i doing wrong here in principle ?

```
#power ite. vanilla
A = np.random.uniform(low=-5.0, high=10.0, size=[3,3])
def power_iteration(A, maxiter, threshold):
    b0 = np.random.rand(A.shape[1])
    it = 0
    error = 0
    while True:
        for i in range(maxiter):
            b1 = np.dot(A, b0)
            b1norm = np.linalg.norm(b1)
            error = np.linalg.norm(b1-b0)
            b0 = b1/b1norm
            domeig = (b0@A@b0)/np.dot(b0, b0)
            
        if error<threshold:
            break
        elif it>maxiter:
            break
        else:
            error = 0
        it = it + 1
    return b0, domeig, it, error

result = power_iteration(A, 10, 0.1)
result
```

The output shows a very correct eigenvalue of ~9 and corresponding eigenvector ( i checked with numpy)

But the error is off. There is no way the length of the difference vector is 8. Considering the result is very close to the actual.

How i want to calculate error is the norm of the difference between the current eigenvector - the previous (b0). I start the error = 0 because the first iteration is guaranteed to give a big difference if b0 is chosen random

```
(array([ 0.06009408,  0.95411524, -0.2933476 ]),
 9.001665234545708,
 11,
 8.001665234545815)
```

Tried to make a loop stop by 2 conditions. One gets ignored

Comment: As a first step, have you simply tried printing the values before the `if` statements…?

Comment: Yes, printing b0, b1, and b1norm would be revealing.  Remember that `b0` is `b1/b1norm`, and in this example `b1norm` is about 9.5.  Expecting `b1-b0` to produce a small number is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work much better like this.

```
def power_it(matrix, iterations, threshold):
    domeigenvector = np.random.rand(matrix.shape[1])
    counter = np.random.rand(matrix.shape[1])
    it = 0
    error = 0
    for i in range(iterations):
        k1 = np.dot(A, domeigenvector)
        k1norm = np.linalg.norm(k1)
        domeigenvector = k1/k1norm
        error = np.linalg.norm(domeigenvector-counter)
        counter = domeigenvector
        domeigenvalue = (domeigenvector@A@domeigenvector)/np.dot(domeigenvector, domeigenvector)
        it = it + 1
        if error < threshold:
            break
    return domeigenvalue, domeigenvector, it
```

I can now use Schur deflation to calculate the rest of the eigenpairs.

Comment: Note that `it` is superfluous, you can use `i` instead.